# How to push or pop from linkedlist Stack

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I have to push and pop from a linkedlist stack, and this is the code I have implemented to push the object on to the top of the stack, however given the constructor i dont understand how to pop something out of the stack.

this is the code i have for push

```
public void push(Q obj) {
  Node<Q> node = new Node(obj);
    if (top == null) {
        top = node;
    } 
    else {
        node.setNext(top);
        top = node;
    }

    length++;
}
```

And this is the constructor i have been given for Pop

```
Public T pop() {


    //Change the return statement 
    return null;
}
```

these are the variables i have defined on the top of my code

```
 private int length = 0;


private Node<Q> top = null;
```

Comment: *And this is the constructor i have been given for Pop* - Are you sure you mean `constructor ` - I think you want a method that will operate on the `top` variable

Comment: Yeah that is *not* a constructor.  (What your instructor is asking you to do is to look at the push method, understand it, and then basically do the reverse.  Maybe start by drawing a diagram of the structure it creates, that might help you.)

Answer (score 2):

First, that is not a constructor for pop. Read what a constructor is and how it is used in class.

In  your code, Node is being pushed at the front of the linked list and top points to the recent node inserted.

So during pop, you need to remove current top and modify top to point to second last node pushed. Store the current top to some temporary variable, move the top node to point to the second last and return the temporary variable.

```
public T pop() {
    if(top!=null){
      Node<Q> temp = top;
      top = top.next;
      temp.next = null;
      return temp;
     }
    return null;
}
```